# angular6:material-nav component create build errors "Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'."

Tags: angular6

I am trying to do universal rendering in my angular6 app.For this I trying to create build of my app using the command 'npm run build:ssr',but it shows following error.

```
ERROR in src\app\app.component.html(7,5): : Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
src\app\app.component.html(8,5): : Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
src\app\app.component.html(6,5): : Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
src\app\app.component.html(23,9): : Property 'isHandset$' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/about',{outlets:{fchild:['firstChild'],schild:['']}}]">ABOUT</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Application Title</span>
    </mat-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  }
```

in the above code I am using material design in my angular app and 'isHandset$' property is part of the material design.can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported MatSidenavModule into your app.module.ts?